# angledown icon in react-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: css, reactjs, formik, react-bootstrap-typeahead

Using typeahead inside formik and
having tough time to add the fa-angle-up and fa-angle-down icons for react-bootstrap-typeahead as below image

[image]

instead i have problem like below(it should look like above image)

[image]

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-8m6o6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. We have added one element `custom-dropdown` and put FontAwesomeIcon and Typeahead element inside this.

In `.custom-dropdown` we set `position: relative;` and

In `.fa-angle-down` we set `position: absolute;` and also set its position as per your requirement.

Please refer to this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-uupel

Comment: I am new to frontend and that worked just perfect

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

**React imports:**

```
import { TiArrowSortedDown } from 'react-icons/ti';
```

**React return statement:**

```
   <>          
    <div className={styles.typeaheadStyles}>
    <Typeahead
        className={...}
        onChange={(event)=>handleChange(event)}
        onInputChange={(event)=>handleInputChange(event)}
        key={...}
        id={...}
        options={optionsArray}
        flip
        defaultSelected={defaultArray}
    />
   <TiArrowSortedDown className={styles.arrowDown} />
   </div>      
   </>
```

**CSS:**

```
.typeaheadStyles{
    align-items: center;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    background-color: "gray";
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;

}
```